# Highlight drop areas in HTML drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm building Yet Another Drag'n'Drop File Uploader. What I'd like to do is highlight the drop area on the page when a drag is started, so the user knows where to move the file to. *The interface doesn't make it explicit straight away, which is desired in this case...*

Highlighting the dropzone when the user is already over it is fine, but it's the time when the user is dragging but not yet in a droppable area that I'd like to be notified of.

I'm not able to use the `dragstart` event, since that fires on the HTML Element which is being dragged, and in this case, it's a file from the user's desktop or something. I also tried the following:

```
$(document.body).on('dragenter', changeTheCSSClass)
                .on('dragleave', changeItBackAgain);
```

However, the enter and leave events fire for every single nested element that the cursor is over, so I get tons of events and the class switches back and forth continuously. Definitely not what I want there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As no one posted anything I am posting this, neither stable nor 100% working, but sometimes working.

```
changeback = 2;
changedback = true;
$(document)
    .off('dragenter dragleave')
    .on('dragenter', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.clearTimeout(changeback);
        changeback = 0;
        console.log('dragenter', e.target);
        if (changedback) document.getElementById('nav-askquestion').style.color = '#bc0000';
        changedback = false;
    }, 10);
})
    .on('dragleave', function (e) {
    console.log('dragleave', e.target);
    if (changeback == 0) {
        changeback = window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('changed back');
            document.getElementById('nav-askquestion').style.color = '#FFFFFF';
            changedback = true;
        }, 15);
    }
});
```

Applied to this page itself. Also you will need to cancel inhouse drags by setting some flag on `dragstart`.

the names `dragenter` and `dragleave` should be actually `dragover` and `dragout` it seems :)

How is it going at your end?

Comment: Thanks for the effort here, but that feels too hacky for me.

Comment: @nickf yes even for me, bit tooo much hacky :) hope specification writers will take care of your case in future. If you find some solution post here

Answer (score 0):

You could use angularJS:

```
<div align="center" class="alert alert-success ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" 
    ngf-select="onPrepareFile($file)" ngf-drop="onPrepareFile($file)" ng-model="vm.file" 
    name="inputFileStorage" 
    ngf-pattern="'image/*,application/pdf'" 
    ngf-accept="'image/*,application/pdf'" 
    ngf-max-size="10MB">
        <a ng-show="!file"><strong>Select or Drop File Here</strong></a>
        <a ng-show="file" class="ng-hide"><strong class="ng-binding"> has been Loaded</strong></a>
</div>
```

In the example I am limiting to a PDF with 10MB max size.

I use TS to code, sorry for the generated code, but can't find original TS...

```
this.onPrepareFile = function (file) {
    if (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            // yOUR FILE INFO IS IN: reader.result
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
};
```